# What is the fastest way to install a wireguard vpn server with a oneliner bash script on a Ubuntu server?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, vpn, wireguard

Looking through some of the wireguard tutorials. It seems daunting to setup a wireguard server with the creation of keys and configuring network files. Is there a quick fast way to install wireguard on a ubuntu server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can install it with one line using this:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/l-n-s/wireguard-install/master/wireguard-install.sh -O wireguard-install.sh
```

Then run the command as the root user:

```
bash wireguard-install.sh
```

Select the options you like. When done, just copy the client details to your computer or phone. This is also stored as a client file in your /root folder as backup.